# Need to install 64bit by replacing 32bit windows os on uefi laptop

Tags: windows, installation, uefi, operating-systems

I installed Windows 7 32bit OS in my laptop (uefi) and am facing some issues like disk drive&wireless after that. I want to install 64 bit OS. Not able to boot with disk drive or usb, since I have issue because of uefi. Please help me

Comment: Why do you expect the 64bit OS to solve these problems?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure when you create a bootable OS drive configured targeted system option is " BIOS or UEFI". 
to create bootable drive use Rufus Software.
link:https://rufus.ie/ AND follow instruction.